# How to ignore editor bash alias in git config?

Tags: git, bash, editor, alias, git-config

In my bashrc, I alias `vim` to `vimer -t`. vimer is a wrapper around vim to open `vim -g` (`gvim`) and open every call to `vim` in the same gui.

Unfortunately, this does not work well with git, as if git opens the commit editor, it opens in the running gvim instance and waits until the complete gvim instance closes. So I cannot edit a commit message and close the vim tab and the `git commit` call completes.

It seems like there is not workaround for this. Therefore, I'd like `git` to call `vim` - but as `git` does call this and recognizes the bash alias, it calls `vimer -t`.

So how can I tell git to ignore the bash alias for my `core.editor` setting to actually call commandline `vim`?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure it by using vim's full path:

```
git config --global core.editor /usr/bin/vim
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this _also_ calls gvim. It is not aliased or so. Note that I'm on NixOS and `which vim` yields `/run/current-system/sw/bin/vim`, but that shouldn't matter in this context. I used `git config --global core.editor $(which vim)` and confirmed that the .gitconfig was set correctly.

Comment: strange. try to trace the git commit command, to see which config file it reads and how it gets to this editor

Comment: My fault: I had an environment variable `GIT_EDITOR` that obviousely overrides the gitconfig settings.